# Predicate Logic Truth Values

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am given

**universe of discourse: Z**

**predicate symbols: q**

**interpretation: $q(x,y) \iff  x + y = 5$**

There are two questions two questions which I don't understand:

i) $∀x.∃y.q(x,y)$ is true, I found it to be false

ii) $∀y.∃x.q(x,y)$ is true, I found it to be false

An explanation would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the two statements are true?

Comment: $∀x.∃y.q(x,y)$ means "For any (all) $x$, there is a $y$ such that $x+y = 5$". Doesn't that seem reasonable to you? What counterexample $x$ have you found, since you found the statement to be false?

Comment: I found that if x > 5, no values of y can make the sum = 5 given that y > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$∀x.∃y.q(x,y)$ is true because for any x you can choose y to be $(5-x)$ and $q(x,y)$ will be true. Same for the second question.